# An integration test with the real database

Tags: database, go, testing, integration-testing

In my integration test, I want to check how my code works with a real database instance (Postgresql). I don't need to mock it. It has to be a real database.
It would be great if I can run test in parallel.
My code contains database transactions.

To share the connection I've created a `db` package:

```
package db

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)

var cachedDBConn *sqlx.DB

func GetConnection(host string, port uint16, user string, password string, databaseName string) (*sqlx.DB, error) {
    if cachedDBConn != nil {
        return cachedDBConn, nil
    }
    dbConnStr := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        host, port, user, password, databaseName)
    cachedDBConn, err := sqlx.Open("postgres", dbConnStr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return cachedDBConn, nil
}

// allow to redefine connection settings for tests in CI
var (
    dbHost     = flag.String("test.dbhost", "localhost", "Test Database host address")
    dbPort     = flag.Int("test.dbport", 5432, "Test Database port number")
    dbUser     = flag.String("test.dbuser", "ccm_test", "Test Database user name")
    dbPassword = flag.String("test.dbpass", "ccm_test", "Test Database user password")
    dbName     = flag.String("test.dbname", "ezan_ccm_test", "Test Database name")
)

// MustGetTestConnection panics if can't create connection
func MustGetTestConnection() (conn *sqlx.DB) {
    db, err := GetConnection(*dbHost, uint16(*dbPort), *dbUser, *dbPassword, *dbName)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to create DB connection: %v", err))
    }
    return db
}
```

I've already saw a solution with [temp schema fo Postgres](https://hackernoon.com/integration-test-with-database-in-golang-355dc123fdc9) and [a solution with revert fuction](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/dmuxx8/test_with_database/)

**What method is better to use respecting parallel run and transactions?**

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can utilize [TestMain](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#M) to initialize your db and load data into it.

Comment: @iLoveReflection I'm at starting point to do that. Earlier I did mocks for such tasks. I sew some solutions: temp schema [1] https://hackernoon.com/integration-test-with-database-in-golang-355dc123fdc9 and [2] https://medium.com/kongkow-it-medan/parallel-database-integration-test-on-go-application-8706b150ee2e, and a solution with create/revert functions here [3] https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/dmuxx8/test_with_database/

Comment: @mkopriva But what approach to use at individual test? What if you need firt try Add, List, Update operations. And the List() would expect a predefined list.

Comment: @Dr.eel if you want to test multiple queries that depend on each other then test them within a single test function, e.g. `TestAddAndList`...

Comment: @Dr.eel if you want to test queries separately, and you want to make sure that the data from one query does not conflict with the data from another query, then execute those queries in their own test functions and execute them within transactions.

Comment: @mkopriva this way thay won't be Parallel.

Comment: @Dr.eel those that depend on each other should not be parallel, how else would you make sure that add is executed before list? Those that are separate and are executed in their own functions will be parallel, i mean its subject to how they are then executed by `go test` but since they are in their own test functions there's no synchronization between them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201923/discussion-between-dr-eel-and-mkopriva).